# react native gesture handler htmlelement is not defined error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-drawer, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-windows

I installed react native with the react native for windows workflow and wanted to implement a drawer navigatior.
following the instructions from here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator

After this my App.jsx looks like this:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button style={{ color: 'red' }}
        title="Go to Details... again"
        onPress={() => navigation.push('Details')}
      />
      <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button style={{ color: 'red' }}
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The debugger throws then the error

> 'PanGestureHandler must be used as a descendant of GestureHandlerRootView. Otherwise the gestures will not be recognized. See [https://docs.swmansion.com/...'](https://docs.swmansion.com/...%27)

So I also followed the instructions in there and installed the GestureHandlerRootView as a root element above the NavigationContainer.

Now I get the error 'HTMLElement is not defined' in the installed package react-native-gesture-handler.
Specifically in the file react-native-gesture-handler\src\RNGestureHandlerModule.windows.ts

```
attachGestureHandler(
    handlerTag: number,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    newView: any,
    _actionType: ActionType,
    propsRef: React.RefObject<unknown>
  ) {
    if (
 -->     !(newView instanceof HTMLElement || newView instanceof React.Component)
    ) {
      return;
    }

    if (isNewWebImplementationEnabled()) {
      //@ts-ignore Types should be HTMLElement or React.Component
      NodeManager.getHandler(handlerTag).init(newView, propsRef);
    } else {
      //@ts-ignore Types should be HTMLElement or React.Component
      HammerNodeManager.getHandler(handlerTag).setView(newView, propsRef);
    }
  },
  updateGestureHandler(handlerTag: number, newConfig: Config) {
    if (isNewWebImplementationEnabled()) {
      NodeManager.getHandler(handlerTag).updateGestureConfig(newConfig);

      InteractionManager.getInstance().configureInteractions(
        NodeManager.getHandler(handlerTag),
        newConfig
      );
    } else {
      HammerNodeManager.getHandler(handlerTag).updateGestureConfig(newConfig);
    }
  }
```

I researched possible solutions for the error regarding this package and module. Did not find anything.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve the problem?
I fixed it by adding this line to the babel.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```